# Selected value should collapsed in navbar using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to design a navigation bar something like this on tablet and larger screen.
[image: desktop navbar]

And this should be something like this on smaller screen.
[image: smaller screen]

**On clicking toggle button all the data should be vertically aligned.**

I tried few things but didn't work. Is it possible with only using bootstrap ? If yes how to approach this.

Here is the code that I've tried (not exact as I'm changing it too much).

```
code
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uzutkww7/)

*ps:- Using bootstrap3*

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you don't use the bootstrap grid

Inside `<div class="row"></div>`, the boostrap grid is divided in 12 equal parts with 4 width size breakpoints. For the details you should read [Boostrap 3 Grid documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid)